# Why spark application fail with "executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated"?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When i execute query sql via spark-submit and spark-sql, corresponding spark application always fail with error follows:

```
15/03/10 18:50:52 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave79:35643] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
```

and above is just one of the error, i used "yarn logs -application application_1425944520319_8102.log" to obtain the whole application log and screen out the error as below:

```
Line 46: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave09:55156] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 97: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave09:32852] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 149: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave09:45654] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 200: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave10:45702] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 251: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave10:21596] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 302: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave10:58845] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 353: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave13:1697] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 437: 15/03/10 18:52:06 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: error creating legacy BlockReaderLocal.  Disabling legacy local reads.
Line 481: 15/03/10 18:52:06 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10)
Line 504: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave13:6289] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 556: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave14:37070] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 607: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave14:43424] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 658: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave15:38083] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 710: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave15:3106] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 761: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave15:35533] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 812: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave16:63207] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 863: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave16:11250] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 910: 15/03/10 18:52:09 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
Line 961: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave18:26917] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1012: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave18:3058] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1063: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave19:1885] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1114: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave19:14795] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1165: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave19:39794] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1216: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave20:19614] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1267: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave20:38776] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1318: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave21:19231] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1370: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave21:18816] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1454: 15/03/10 18:52:06 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: error creating legacy BlockReaderLocal.  Disabling legacy local reads.
Line 1498: 15/03/10 18:52:06 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18)
Line 1524: 15/03/10 18:52:06 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 28)
Line 1550: 15/03/10 18:52:06 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 31)
Line 1576: 15/03/10 18:52:06 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 32)
Line 1602: 15/03/10 18:52:06 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.4 in stage 0.0 (TID 33)
Line 1628: 15/03/10 18:52:07 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.5 in stage 0.0 (TID 36)
Line 1654: 15/03/10 18:52:07 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.6 in stage 0.0 (TID 37)
Line 1680: 15/03/10 18:52:07 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.7 in stage 0.0 (TID 39)
Line 1706: 15/03/10 18:52:07 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.8 in stage 0.0 (TID 41)
Line 1732: 15/03/10 18:52:07 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.9 in stage 0.0 (TID 42)
Line 1755: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave22:24322] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1806: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave23:38508] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1858: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave24:19707] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1909: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave25:33683] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 1976: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave25:18587] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2027: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave26:64531] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2078: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave27:23333] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2129: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave27:61136] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2180: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave27:25118] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2231: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave28:16274] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2282: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave29:1324] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2334: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave29:51664] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2385: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave29:38854] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2452: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave30:30088] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2504: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave30:30778] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2556: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave31:52263] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2623: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave31:17806] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2674: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave32:3251] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2725: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave32:17832] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2776: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave32:11629] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2827: 15/03/10 18:52:08 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave33:22629] -> [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@slave75:60697] disassociated! Shutting down.
Line 2911: 15/03/10 18:52:07 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: error creating legacy BlockReaderLocal.  Disabling legacy local reads.
```

you can get the log file from https://www.dropbox.com/s/lf50ger18v3ngtb/application_1425944520319_8102.log?dl=0 if i didn't express clearly.

The network of slave75 is ok and hosts in all nodes are correctly configured.
Any response will help, thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? If yes, can you port the solution?

Comment: hi @Bhushan, the reason is my network card was in trouble

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally I found the reason. It is because Yarn kills the executor (container) because the executor is memory overhead. Just turn up values of `spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead` or `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` or both.

Comment: Can you tell me how you figured that out?

Comment: How did you find the cause? I am having this issue while using Spark 1.6.1 for maximum likelihood estimation with EM algorithm. My data is small, which is less than 100MB. I don't understand why memory overhead's are so important. BTW, I am using pyspark. Is it because spark needs more overhead to lead the python libraries?

Comment: I have had this issue just now, it has been almost impossible to find the error. I am running on AWS EMR. After all I ve found the error log on Spark History on port :18080 on executers stdout and stderror

Comment: i saw the error logs on emr log => steps/stderr  that driver memory is not enough , so increased it with step conf --driver-memory 6g

Comment: @zwb I am getting the same error. I played around with the number of executor and executor memory, still no luck. Also tried the above parameters but no luck again,`17/01/03 15:46:13 INFO SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: attempt_201701031545_0015_m_000125_0: Committed
17/01/03 15:46:13 INFO Executor: Finished task 125.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 2083). 1357 bytes result sent to driver
17/01/03 15:47:14 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/01/03 15:47:14 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
17/01/03 15:47:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the worker G.1X. After upgrading worker type to G.2X my task could finish ETL of 20 million rows of DataFrame.

```
GlueJob:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Job
  Properties:
    GlueVersion: '2.0'
    NumberOfWorkers: '3'
    WorkerType: 'G.2X'
```

Answer (score 0):

One datapoint: this issue was resolved by increasing the **spark driver/ k8s master pod's requested memory**. I'm using [client mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#client-mode) on Kubernetes.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I resolve this problem by increasing the number of parallel task that read data to RDD

Comment: How did you figure that as a root cause?