# Spark job failing when the spark context is getting shut down, everything else is working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I have a job that runs periodically on spark (hadoop version 3.1.1), written in Scala. 
I can tell the job finished successfully because we get a summary email and the files are where they should be, but when the spark context is shutting down it errors out for some reason:

Example 1:

```
20/03/20 10:55:16 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 3170
20/03/20 10:55:47 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver <server-name> disassociated! Shutting down.
20/03/20 10:55:47 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
20/03/20 10:55:48 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
20/03/20 10:55:48 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Example 2:

```
20/03/20 12:57:22 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver <server-name> disassociated! Shutting down.
20/03/20 12:57:22 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
20/03/20 12:57:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967500/why-spark-application-fail-with-executor-coarsegrainedexecutorbackend-driver-d

Comment: I tried that and it did not work

Comment: Try increasing spark.driver.memory & spark.executor.memory